# Ansible can't stop managed service

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a `Spring Boot` application managed as a `systemd` service on a `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.7 (Maipo)` cluster. The service unit configuration is all right, I can directly `start` and `stop` the service unit **by hand** on the system that I'm trying to command/control with `Ansible 2.8.5`.

The process owner is `tomcat` and I'm using another user (`deployer`) that can "become" `tomcat` and run the commands on the hosts. That's fine for some other actions, but it fails when I put the actions to manage the service (I've tried with both `systemd` and `service` modules):

```
# ./ansible/roles/boot-core/tasks/main.yml
---
- name: "Deploy/Install new application"
  block:
#    - name: "Make sure {{ service_id }} is stopped"
#      systemd:
#        name: "{{ service_id }}"
#        state: stopped
    - name: "Make sure {{ service_id }} is stopped"
      service:
        name: "{{ service_id }}"
        state: stopped
#    - name: "Make sure {{ service_id }} is enabled and started"
#      systemd:
#        enabled: yes
#        name: "{{ service_id }}"
#        state: started
    - name: "Make sure {{ service_id }} is enabled and started"
      service:
        enabled: yes
        name: "{{ service_id }}"
        state: started
```

```
# ./ansible/site.yml
---
- hosts: webservers
  any_errors_fatal: true
  become_user: tomcat
  become: yes
  force_handlers: true
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - boot-core
```

...and this is how I'm running the playbook as `deployer` (on a GitLab pipeline, the syntax is different, so I convert it here to what it would look like in a UN*X shell):

```sh
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
$ ssh-add <(echo "${PRIVATE_SSH_KEY}")
$ ansible-playbook -vvv \
    --extra-vars CI_PIPELINE_ID="${CI_PIPELINE_ID}" \
    --extra-vars CI_PROJECT_DIR="${CI_PROJECT_DIR}" \
    --inventory-file "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/infrastructure/ansible/inventories/${ANSIBLE_INVENTORY}" \
    --limit webservers
    --user deployer
    "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/infrastructure/ansible/site.yml"
```

This is what's getting printed in the logs:

```sh
TASK [boot-core : Make sure boot-core is stopped] ****************************
task path: /builds/x80486/boot-core/infrastructure/ansible/roles/boot-core/tasks/main.yml:58
<unixvm001> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deployer
<unixvm001> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="deployer"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ea5c024329 unixvm001 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~deployer && sleep 0'"'"''
<unixvm001> (0, '/usr/local/home/deployer\n', "Warning: Permanently added 'unixvm001,10.5.177.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n\t\t\t\n")
<unixvm001> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deployer
<unixvm001> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="deployer"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ea5c024329 unixvm001 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620="` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<unixvm001> (0, 'ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620=/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620\n', '')
<unixvm001> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<unixvm001> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deployer
<unixvm001> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="deployer"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ea5c024329 unixvm001 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python3.5'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.7'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python2.6'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; command -v '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'python'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'"'"''
<unixvm001> (0, 'PLATFORM\nLinux\nFOUND\n/usr/bin/python\n/usr/bin/python2.7\n/usr/libexec/platform-python\n/usr/bin/python\nENDFOUND\n', '')
<unixvm001> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deployer
<unixvm001> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="deployer"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ea5c024329 unixvm001 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python && sleep 0'"'"''
<unixvm001> (0, '{"osrelease_content": "NAME=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server\\"\\nVERSION=\\"7.7 (Maipo)\\"\\nID=\\"rhel\\"\\nID_LIKE=\\"fedora\\"\\nVARIANT=\\"Server\\"\\nVARIANT_ID=\\"server\\"\\nVERSION_ID=\\"7.7\\"\\nPRETTY_NAME=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.7 (Maipo)\\"\\nANSI_COLOR=\\"0;31\\"\\nCPE_NAME=\\"cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.7:GA:server\\"\\nHOME_URL=\\"https://www.redhat.com/\\"\\nBUG_REPORT_URL=\\"https://bugzilla.redhat.com/\\"\\n\\nREDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7\\"\\nREDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.7\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT=\\"Red Hat Enterprise Linux\\"\\nREDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=\\"7.7\\"\\n", "platform_dist_result": ["redhat", "7.7", "Maipo"]}\n', '')
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<unixvm001> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-4292hN1DYR/tmpYM8xgh TO /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620/AnsiballZ_setup.py
<unixvm001> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="deployer"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ea5c024329 '[unixvm001]'
<unixvm001> (0, 'sftp> put /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-4292hN1DYR/tmpYM8xgh /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620/AnsiballZ_setup.py\n', '')
<unixvm001> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deployer
<unixvm001> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="deployer"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ea5c024329 unixvm001 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'setfacl -m u:tomcat:r-x /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620/ /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<unixvm001> (0, '', '')
<unixvm001> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deployer
<unixvm001> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="deployer"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ea5c024329 -tt unixvm001 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u tomcat /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-ldekvnpzwgrgribssedqdqimvuzpvozm ; /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620/AnsiballZ_setup.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
<unixvm001> (0, '\r\n{"invocation": {"module_args": {"filter": "ansible_service_mgr", "gather_subset": ["!all"], "fact_path": "/etc/ansible/facts.d", "gather_timeout": 10}}, "ansible_facts": {"ansible_service_mgr": "systemd"}}\r\n', 'Shared connection to unixvm001 closed.\r\n')
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/systemd.py
<unixvm001> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-4292hN1DYR/tmpuOv4ys TO /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620/AnsiballZ_systemd.py
<unixvm001> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="deployer"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ea5c024329 '[unixvm001]'
<unixvm001> (0, 'sftp> put /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-4292hN1DYR/tmpuOv4ys /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620/AnsiballZ_systemd.py\n', '')
<unixvm001> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deployer
<unixvm001> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="deployer"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ea5c024329 unixvm001 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'setfacl -m u:tomcat:r-x /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620/ /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620/AnsiballZ_systemd.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<unixvm001> (0, '', '')
<unixvm001> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deployer
<unixvm001> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="deployer"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ea5c024329 -tt unixvm001 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u tomcat /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-nnwsmnabevfloceodiibjgkauxvxykgu ; /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620/AnsiballZ_systemd.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
<unixvm001> (1, '\x1b[1;31m==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===\r\n\x1b[0mAuthentication is required to manage system services or units.\r\nAuthenticating as: Unix Admin (rsc_sys)\r\nPassword: \r\n{"msg": "Unable to stop service boot-core: Failed to stop boot-core.service: Connection timed out\\nSee system logs and \'systemctl status boot-core.service\' for details.\\n", "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"no_block": false, "force": null, "name": "boot-core", "daemon_reexec": false, "enabled": null, "daemon_reload": false, "state": "stopped", "masked": null, "scope": null, "user": null}}}\r\n', 'Shared connection to unixvm001 closed.\r\n')
<unixvm001> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to unixvm001 closed.
<unixvm001> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: deployer
<unixvm001> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="deployer"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ea5c024329 unixvm001 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571756098.47-177915759067620/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<unixvm001> (0, '', '')
fatal: [unixvm001]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    }, 
    "changed": false, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "daemon_reexec": false, 
            "daemon_reload": false, 
            "enabled": null, 
            "force": null, 
            "masked": null, 
            "name": "boot-core", 
            "no_block": false, 
            "scope": null, 
            "state": "stopped", 
            "user": null
        }
    }, 
    "msg": "Unable to stop service boot-core: Failed to stop boot-core.service: Connection timed out\nSee system logs and 'systemctl status boot-core.service' for details.\n"
}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
unixvm001 : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I remembered I've seen this message: `Authentication is required to manage system services or units.\r\nAuthenticating as: Unix Admin (rsc_sys)` before when `sudo` privileges were not applied correctly on the hosts and I was trying to `start` / `stop` the service unit by hand, but I'm not sure why it's showing up with `Ansible` here now.

This is what I get when I do `sudo -l`:

```sh
[deployer@unixvm001 ~]$ sudo -l 
Matching Defaults entries for deployer on unixvm001:
    ignore_dot, !mail_no_user, !root_sudo, !syslog, timestamp_timeout=10, logfile=/var/log/sudo.log, pwfeedback, passwd_timeout=5, passwd_tries=3, umask_override,
    umask=0027, log_host, visiblepw, env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK, ignore_dot, !mail_no_user, !root_sudo, !syslog, timestamp_timeout=10, logfile=/var/log/sudo.log, pwfeedback,
    passwd_timeout=5, passwd_tries=3, umask_override, umask=0027, log_host, visiblepw, env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK

User deployer may run the following commands on unixvm001:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/multipath -ll, /sbin/ifconfig -a, /usr/bin/ipmitool lan print, /usr/sbin/dmidecode -s system-product-name, /usr/sbin/dmidecode -s
        system-serial-number, /usr/bin/last, /usr/sbin/nscd -i hosts, /usr/local/bin/ports, /bin/cat /var/log/dmesg
    (oem) NOPASSWD: /usr/oem/agent/agent_inst/bin/emctl, /opt/oracle-oem/bin/emctl, /usr/oem/bin/emctl, /opt/oracle-oem/agent/agent_inst/bin/emctl,
        /u01/oracle/agent/agent_inst/bin/emctl
    (tomcat) NOPASSWD: ALL, !/bin/su
    (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl * tomcat*, /bin/view /var/log/messages, /bin/systemctl * boot-core*, /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
    (tomcat) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl * boot-core*
```

Again, on the hosts I can do: `sudo /bin/systemctl stop boot-core.service` (same with `start`) and everything is fine, although if I do only `systemctl stop boot-core.service` I would get the same error message:

```sh
[deployer@unixvm001~]$ systemctl stop boot-core.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Authenticating as: Unix Admin (rsc_sys)
Password:
```

Any clues what's going on here? I believe the `sudo` privileges should be tweaked, but I'm not entirely sure.

---

**UPDATE:**

I modified the Ansible script (just for testing) to use the `command` module:

```
- name: "Make sure {{ service_id }} is stopped"
  command: "sudo systemctl stop {{ service_id }}"
- name: "Make sure {{ service_id }} is started"
  command: "sudo systemctl start {{ service_id }}"
```

...and it "does work" (though I have to use `sudo`, it **does not** work using `become: yes` and removing `sudo` from the command):

```sh
Oct 24 13:29:35 : deployer : HOST=unixvm001 : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/usr/local/home/deployer ; USER=tomcat ; COMMAND=/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-acdbbxcaetxxlfgnnbvtmrxcofktyjnw ; /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571938173.5-172296377610468/AnsiballZ_command.py
Oct 24 13:29:36 : tomcat : HOST=unixvm001 : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/usr/local/home/tomcat/.ansible/tmp/ansible-moduletmp-1571938175.42-_jtzB0 ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl stop boot-core.service
Oct 24 13:29:37 : deployer : HOST=unixvm001 : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/usr/local/home/deployer ; USER=tomcat ; COMMAND=/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-utdnsysqmyzkactqhadmmoiujwounyru ; /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1571938176.98-167412210657077/AnsiballZ_command.py
Oct 24 13:29:37 : tomcat : HOST=unixvm001 : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/usr/local/home/tomcat/.ansible/tmp/ansible-moduletmp-1571938177.75-k7qyDh ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start boot-core.service

---

Oct 24 13:29:37 unixvm001 python: ansible-command Invoked with creates=None executable=None _uses_shell=False strip_empty_ends=True _raw_params=sudo systemctl start boot-core.service removes=None argv=None warn=True chdir=None stdin_add_newline=True stdin=None
Oct 24 13:29:37 unixvm001 python: ansible-command [WARNING] Consider using 'become', 'become_method', and 'become_user' rather than running sudo
```

Comment: See [Can’t limit escalation to certain commands](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#can-t-limit-escalation-to-certain-commands) i.e. there must be a user(or root) able to run ``systemctl stop boot-core.service``.

Comment: But I can do, for instance, `sudo systemctl stop boot-core.service` while logged on the hosts as `deployer`, and I do also have `become_method: enable`, `become_user: tomcat`, and `become: yes` on the playbook. Wouldn't that be the same?

Comment: ``become_method: enable`` is different.  I can't find it in the question.

Comment: Well, I didn't put the entire playbook, it's all split in different files; I'm going to update the question with the `site.yml` file. In the end, I think it's an issue with the `tomcat` user; I did `sudo su - tomcat`, and while logged as such then, I'm getting exactly the same error I see when running via `Ansible`, so I think that user should be "beef up" in order to run those commands.

Comment: @paul, I never found a solution for this because the account I was using to control/manage the servers via Ansible was restricted to the bones. If for some reason you are able to overcome that (and the privileges are assigned correctly) you wouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're running a playbook as the `tomcat` user but then trying to manage a service, this won't work. If you ssh into that machine as the `tomcat` user and just try to run a `systemctl` command without escalating privileges then it won't work by hand either. It seems as though you're telling the playbook to do one thing and then doing a completely different thing by hand and calling them equivalent but that one of them isn't working properly. I suspect this is not the case (but I could be wrong and bugs do happen).

You could either break this up as multiple plays, each play set to different users, or with appropriate `become` options and divide the tasks that way. Alternatively, you can set privilege escalation for those tasks specifically (or at the block level). https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html

Comment: I updated the question; I'm connecting to the hosts as `deployer`, then "becoming" `tomcat`, then doing `sudo systemctl [start / stop] boot-core.service`...and that works. The `deployer` user has in the `sudo` privileges `(tomcat) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl * boot-core*`, so I thought that's exactly the same like I was doing in the playbook.

Comment: When you run `sudo systemctl ....` as the `tomcat` user, it's effectively run as root (by default anyways, pending your system config).

Try:

```
---
- name: "Deploy/Install new application"
  block:
    - name: "Make sure {{ service_id }} is stopped"
      service:
        name: "{{ service_id }}"
        state: stopped
      become: true
    - name: "Make sure {{ service_id }} is enabled and started"
      service:
        enabled: yes
        name: "{{ service_id }}"
        state: started
      become: true
```

Comment: Also note, `become` is the Ansible playbook substitute for `sudo` (can do way more than just sudo, but in this case it's basically `sudo`)

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting the same error(s). I talked to the admin group, and they confirmed that the user `tomcat` must run the command(s) like `sudo systemctl start|stop|status boot-core`...and I thought that your suggestion was to do that exactly.

Comment: By the way, I see this entry for `sudo -l` while logged as tomcat: `(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/systemctl * boot-core*`, hence `tomcat` has the ability to `sudo` as `root` and run `systemctl` on that service, so I think that should be OK.

Comment: That is great, that will take care of the permissions on the system side, but you still need to define the `become: true` on the tasks so that Ansible knows it needs to run those tasks with `sudo` (the default `become` method).

Comment: Indeed, I tried your recommendation, but it gives me the same error message. It has to be something on the hosts I'm trying to control/command via Ansible. Putting `become: yes` (again) in the `service` tasks doesn't do anything for me, it looks like it cannot become `root`; on the other hand, if I so also specify `become_user: root` (along with  `become: yes`), it asks me for a password. The trend here is to manage those servers with scripts made by another team.

Comment: try `become: yes` and `become_user: tomcat` (which seems redundant, but I think in this instance the task needs to know to actually run `sudo` but that the user it needs to `tomcat` since `tomcat` has the appropriate sudo permissions. I'm honestly just guessing at this point because I've never seen this type of situation. Typically the `tomcat` user on systems is unprivileged.

Comment: I tried that also...but no luck. I can't even see the logs on the systems, I have to request those every time (it's frustrating); I think this is not an Ansible problem because every example out there is how I currently have it. I ended up using `command: "sudo systemctl stop {{ service_id }}"`, that's the only way this works. The reason they tell me that `deployer` can't become `root` and be able to manage some stuff is because it's an uncontrolled account (meaning it has a key that can be compromised) so they don't provide additional direct capabilities. In any case, thank you so much!

Comment: I've unfortunately exhausted all the things I cant think of, from here I would need to know about system configurations and log info to really be of any help because there's clearly something weird going on. What I would suggest is bump the verbosity all the way up and debug output (log it locally for good measure) with `ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=~/ansible.log ANSIBLE_DEBUG=True ansible-playbook foo.yml -vvvvv`. It's possible that will give you some clues. If you can post that info sanitized somewhere I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Thanks, Adam! I put those parameters in the pipeline and I ran it again...this time the amount of logging is huge: https://pastehero.com/view/20191030-ee1cbd63-0e1a-420-9f44-2cdbde405cac ...still, I don't see anything that gives me any clues on this — but as you might have guessed, I have limited knowledge on this subject.

Comment: Alright, so it looks like somewhere in the process (either due to something going sideways with Ansible or a config causing unexpected side effects) is auth'ing as the wrong user. I see the following: `Authenticating as: Unix Admin (uscs_sys)` in the `AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units` output line which leads me to believe there's something causing the wrong user account to attempt to manage the service instead of `tomcat`.